# Pagination not working fine after filter product collection

Tags: issue, magento24

We have created two attribute set inside admin area one is default attribute set.

From default attribute set, we have created one more attribute set that is "migrated" which id is "101" in database.

Then, we have created 30 test product with name (test1 , test2, test 3) and assign some product ramdomly from these product to "migrated" attribute set as you can see in below screenshot:

https://nimb.ws/NhxPcn

When we search product using test keyword in search seaction. product collection is filter properly using our observer code but pagination count is wrong and if only page like should show 12 product, but due to our observer code show 10 and remaing product show on next page.

As per tool bar setting product should show like per page 12, 24 and so on.

We have applied following code.

You can download it from below link or help us.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-H-rDoHve4JWLNgoub-xOXbEHLN2RVCi/view?usp=sharing

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide more details about how you apply your custom restrictions to collection. I guess you didn't properly cover `getSize` logic (`getSelectCountSql`)

Comment: Please look detailed description Rajni posted below.

Comment: I have updated it again with detail description.

Answer (score 0):

We have created two attribute set inside admin area one is default attribute set.

From default attribute set, we have created one more attribute set that is "migrated" which id is "101" in database.

Then, we have created 30 test product with name (test1 , test2, test 3) and assign some product ramdomly from these product to "migrated" attribute set as you can see in below screenshot:

https://nimb.ws/NhxPcn

When we search product using test keyword in search seaction. product collection is filter properly but pagination count is wrong and if only page like should show 12 product, but due to our observer code show 10 and remaing product show on next page.

As per tool bar setting product should show like per page 12, 24 and so on.

We also using Magento2.4.3.-p2 and facing the same issue.

We have applied following code.

You can download it from below link or help us.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-H-rDoHve4JWLNgoub-xOXbEHLN2RVCi/view?usp=sharing

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,